# Find a basis with the primal simplex method

Tags: primal-simplex

To solve a minimization problem using the primal simplex firstly we need a basis. If I am not wrong, a variable is basic if it enters into this equation with a coefficient of one. So I have seen solutions where artificial variables are added in order to find a basis and then proceed with the table to find the solution. The problem is that I don't understand where to put the artificial variable and in general how to find the basis.

Here's an example:

$$min z= -2x_1 +2x_2 + 2x_3$$
$$s.t  \; x_1+x_2-2x_3 \geq 1$$
$$x_1+x_2-x_3 \leq 3$$
$$-x_1-x_2+3x_3 \geq -2$$
$$x_1,x_2,x_3 \geq 0$$

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that your variables are nonnegative. (The question does not specify this.) Your first step is to add slack variables to $\le$ constraints and subtract surplus variables in $\ge$ constraints. Any slack variables added will be part of the initial basis. To use what is known as the "two phase simplex" method, you add an artificial variable to each $\ge$ and $=$ constraint, form an initial basis from the artificials and any slacks (but not surpluses), and then change the objective to minimize the sum of the artificial variables.

If the original problem is feasible, the simplex method will pivot all the artificial variables out of the basis, driving the phase 1 objective to zero. At that point, you have a basis feasible in the original problem. Change back to the original objective, remove any artificials from the problem, and resume pivoting (in what is now called phase 2).

There is one edge case to note. If the final phase 1 solution is degenerate, you might still have one or more artificials in the basis (with value 0). You can pivot them out and then get to phase 2.